# Youtube started lagging out of nowhere

Tags: google-chrome, video, youtube

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 a few months ago and youtube was playing well at 1440p. Then it slowly started lagging for no reason. At 1080p i don't have any problems. I'm using chrome browser. I've tried firefox but the video freezes after few seconds. I've also tried changing audio (read it in other posts) but nothing happened. Any help?